# Скролл таблицы на сайте заедает при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, прокрутка, table

Ситуация следующая. Есть таблица на странице сайта, которая не помещается. Я вставил скролл, но он заедает при загрузке страницы: не реагирует на курсор мышки и т.п.
После нескольких секунд скролл начинает работать как надо.

Вот [страница](https://www.vorotasuper.ru/catalog/sekcionnye_vorota/garazhnye/), где размещена таблица со скроллом

Answer (score 0):

Проблему не увидел, все грузится. Либо вы уже решили проблему, либо у меня на не слабом железе она не повторилась.
В любом случае, оптимизировать ваш сайт не помешает, в PageSpeed у него не очень хорошая оценка. Как вариант, подтормаживание было из-за этого.

Comment: Спасибо, Павел, за ваш ответ. Сайт коммерческой организации и вопрос нужно было решать быстро. В итоге, я просто убрал несколько столбцов в таблицах и пропала необходимость в скролле.